# c++ visual studio code error for macbook pro 2022 m2

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I started in college and we had to download visual studio for c++ coding.
I downloaded visual studio code and the required extensions. When I try to do simple code I get the following errors.

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"_main", referenced from:
implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.07 secondsUndefined symbols for architecture arm64:

My code is following:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{

    cout << "hello world";
    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: How exactly are you compiling the code?

Comment: My guess is you did not save your file. VSCode by default does not save a file when you build.

Comment: Ahh thanks Mr Drescherjm. It works finally, Im new to mac os so it takes some time to learn all this!